# World Of Tanks Blitz is not on Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I am very new to Android ecosystem.  I can't seem to locate this game title on Play Store.  Should it be on Google Play Store?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about trying to find a non-existent app in the Play Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the game's official website](http://wotblitz.com/), it's available "exclusively on iPhone, iPad, and iPod Touch". The developer has chosen not to release an Android version.

They may do so at a later date. Often with mobile games, the developer will release on one platform first (usually whichever they're most familiar with) to test how much of a market there is for the game, before porting it to the other platform.

Answer (score 2):

A simple search on the play store gave no results for such a game. If it actually does exist on android, it may not be compatible with your device and therefore won't show up in your play store search results. Only apps that are compatible with your device are shown.

Isn't world of tanks a computer game? Note that not all high end desktop and console games are on android.

EDIT: As the best answer explains, this game isn't available on Android. That means that my answer is irrelevant. However, if you ever have a similar issue in the future, this may still come in useful.